# View system when offline issue

Tags: permissions, system, offline

I have a development site that I've currently set as offline. I created a content administrator members group (which currently has one member) and gave the group permission to view the site when offline. When the one member logs in and attempts to view the site she sees the site offline page. However, when I log in as the same member (same UN, same pass) on my computer I am able to see the site. Thinking that some of my superAdmin privileges might be stored somewhere in my browser I tried logging on as her in a different browser, different computer, and my iPad. In each case I got the same result. I could log in with her credentials and see the site. We set up an Adobe Connect meeting so I can confirm the issue she's having. She's using Firefox in Windows 7, logging in correctly, trying to access the site from the upper right hand link on the CP....and nothing. Based on my tests it seems like the issue is isolated to her system. Can anyone provide some insight to what the problem may be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a caching issue with the other user's device; advise them to attempt to login using a different device and/or browser, or have them clear their cache, whichever's easier.